# I want add points to ggmap with another dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

```
yqmap+
    stat_summary2d(data=b,aes(x=x,y=y,z=pred),fun=median,bins=100,alpha=.5)+
    scale_fill_gradientn(name="车辆数",colours=colormap,space="lab")+
    labs(x="Longitude",y="Latitude")+
    geom_point(data=bike,aes(lon,lat))
```

but I can't save this image by using `ggsave`.

If I plot the image by using this code:

```
pred.stat.map <- ggmap(yuanqu) %+% b + 
    aes(x = x,
        y = y,
        z = b$pred) +
    stat_summary2d(fun = median, 
                   bins=100,
                   alpha = 0.5) + 
    scale_fill_gradientn(name = "Median",
                         colours = colormap,
                         space = "Lab") +
            labs(x = "Longitude",
         y = "Latitude") +
            coord_map() 
print(pred.stat.map)
```

The difference between these two images is the point that display on the image. As you can see, the point and the bins are coming from different dataset. I can't plot what I want using the second code, but I also can't save what I want using the first code.

This is my data and full code and the image that display:
[second code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx3tD.jpg)
[first code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w38MP.jpg)

```
 library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(kriging)

##载入地图
yuanqu<-get_map(location=c(lon=120.735,lat=31.2875),zoom=13,maptype="roadmap")
yqmap<-ggmap(yuanqu)

##读入需要的数据
bike<-read.csv("E:/研究生学习/公共自行车/数据/谷歌坐标版本/湖东独墅湖区点位信息及可借率 高峰平峰(谷歌坐标）.csv",header=T)
##写入热力图需要的数据
x <- bike$lon
y <- bike$lat
z <- bike$八点L
##检查数据是否有重复坐标
coor = cbind(x, y)
duplicated(coor)
coor[duplicated(coor),]
# Krige and create the map
kriged <- kriging(x, y, z,lag=3, polygons=NULL,pixels=100)
image(kriged, xlim = extendrange(x), ylim = extendrange(y))
b<-kriged$map
colormap <- c("Blue","Green","Yellow","Red","White")
pred.stat.map <- ggmap(yuanqu) %+% b + 
        aes(x = x,
            y = y,
            z = b$pred) +
        stat_summary2d(fun = median, 
                       bins=100,
                       alpha = 0.5) + 
        scale_fill_gradientn(name = "Median",
                             colours = colormap,
                             space = "Lab") +
                labs(x = "Longitude",
             y = "Latitude") +
                coord_map()
print(pred.stat.map)

heatmap<-yqmap+
        stat_summary2d(data=b,aes(x=x,y=y,z=pred),fun=median,bins=100,alpha=.5)+
        scale_fill_gradientn(name="车辆数",colours=colormap,space="lab")+
        labs(x="Longitude",y="Latitude")+
        geom_point(data=bike,aes(lon,lat))
heatmap
##保存图片
ggsave(filename = "E:/heat1.png",
       plot = pred.stat.map,
       scale = 1,
       width = 5, height = 3,
       dpi = 300)
```

This is my data：

```
lon,lat,点位名称,group,总桩位数,六点,area,八点,八点半,九点,九点半,十点,六点L,八点L,八点半L,九点L,九点半L,十点L
120.7256,31.31406,枫情水岸南门,1,20,0.6,7,0.1,0.1,0,0.05,0.75,12,12,2,0,1,15
120.7275,31.31115,东湖大郡一期东,1,40,0.775,8,0.25,0.025,0,0,0.025,31,31,1,0,0,1
120.715,31.31642,摩天轮公园,1,28,0.392857143,4,0.392857143,0.392857143,0.428571429,0.392857143,0.428571429,11,11,11,12.00000001,11,12.00000001
120.7003,31.32973,玲珑邻里中心,1,28,0.214285714,3,0.285714286,0.285714286,0.5,0.357142857,0.285714286,5.999999992,5.999999992,8.000000008,14,9.999999996,8.000000008
120.7038,31.32955,中海湖滨一号,1,30,0.5,5,0.1,0.166666667,0.066666667,0.133333333,0.166666667,15,15,5.00000001,2.00000001,3.99999999,5.00000001
120.7263,31.32855,九龙医院西,1,30,0.4,4,0.733333333,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.466666667,12,12,12,12,15,14.00000001
120.7332,31.32798,青少年活动中心西,1,30,0.033333333,1,0.666666667,0.9,0.7,0.5,0.366666667,0.99999999,0.99999999,27,21,15,11.00000001
120.7178,31.32748,中海星湖国际北门,1,30,0.7,7,0.533333333,0.6,0.633333333,0.533333333,0.533333333,21,21,18,18.99999999,15.99999999,15.99999999
120.7212,31.32349,行政服务中心西,1,36,0.027777778,1,0.194444444,0.055555556,0,0,0,1.000000008,1.000000008,2.000000016,0,0,0
120.7264,31.29931,橄榄湾南门,1,30,0.7,7,0.866666667,0.333333333,0.366666667,0.466666667,0.833333333,21,21,9.99999999,11.00000001,14.00000001,24.99999999
120.7395,31.30655,澳韵花园南门,1,30,1,10,0.4,0.233333333,0.133333333,0.166666667,0.166666667,30,30,6.99999999,3.99999999,5.00000001,5.00000001
120.7383,31.31599,湖畔天城南,1,30,0.7,7,0.5,0.033333333,0.033333333,0.133333333,0.033333333,21,21,0.99999999,0.99999999,3.99999999,0.99999999
120.729,31.31476,湖东邻里中心北,1,34,0.117647059,2,0.176470588,0.058823529,0.058823529,0.029411765,0.058823529,4.000000006,4.000000006,1.999999986,1.999999986,1.00000001,1.999999986
120.7204,31.30899,金姬墩公园北,1,20,0.65,7,0.8,0.7,0.85,0.85,0.85,13,13,14,17,17,17
120.7334,31.31752,东城郡东门,1,25,0.44,5,0.08,0,0,0.12,0.16,11,11,0,0,3,4
120.7339,31.31682,金湖湾西门南,1,20,0.3,3,0,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.1,6,6,1,1,1,2
120.7409,31.31863,自由水岸花园西门,1,30,0.833333333,9,0,0,0.033333333,0.033333333,0,24.99999999,24.99999999,0,0.99999999,0.99999999,0
120.7244,31.30963,中塘公园西,1,20,0.1,1,0.55,0.4,0.7,0.6,0.45,2,2,8,14,12,9
120.7248,31.32027,人力资源市场南,1,30,0.033333333,1,0.3,0.566666667,0.633333333,0.733333333,0.5,0.99999999,0.99999999,17.00000001,18.99999999,21.99999999,15
120.7265,31.3233,园区行政中心东,1,40,0.05,1,0.175,0.225,0.7,0.825,0.975,2,2,9,28,33,39
120.7282,31.30543,德邑西门北,1,20,1.5,10,1.05,0.9,0.7,0.65,0.6,30,30,18,14,13,12
120.7337,31.30746,伊顿小镇东门北,1,28,0.892857143,9,0.392857143,0.25,0.357142857,0.357142857,0.428571429,25,25,7,9.999999996,9.999999996,12.00000001
120.7336,31.31131,东湖大郡二期东门,1,25,0.8,8,0.48,0.48,0.6,0.44,0.36,20,20,12,15,11,9
120.7361,31.31252,欧典花园北门西,1,30,0.333333333,4,0.3,0.5,0.166666667,0.5,0.266666667,9.99999999,9.99999999,15,5.00000001,15,8.00000001
120.7419,31.314,方洲邻里中心南,1,30,0.4,4,0.433333333,0.466666667,0.466666667,0.366666667,0.3,12,12,14.00000001,14.00000001,11.00000001,9
120.7456,31.31711,方洲公园北,1,29,0.793103448,8,0.413793103,0.24137931,0.103448276,0.172413793,0.137931034,22.99999999,22.99999999,6.99999999,3.000000004,4.999999997,3.999999986
120.7124,31.31884,圆融时代广场南,1,20,0.3,3,0.55,0.05,0.3,0.5,0.7,6,6,1,6,10,14
120.7456,31.32048,中海国际社区七区,1,40,0.7,7,0,0,0.375,0.3,0.325,28,28,0,15,12,13
120.722,31.2885,水墨江南东门,1,18,0.555555556,6,0.5,0.444444444,0.444444444,0.444444444,0.5,10.00000001,10.00000001,7.999999992,7.999999992,7.999999992,9
120.7166,31.31905,久光百货南,1,26,0.230769231,3,0.538461538,0.153846154,0.884615385,0.346153846,0.769230769,6.000000006,6.000000006,4.000000004,23.00000001,8.999999996,19.99999999
120.7277,31.31357,湖东邻里中心西南,1,20,0.05,1,0.35,0.3,0.15,0.1,0.1,1,1,6,3,2,2
120.7407,31.31129,第五元素小区东门,1,19,0.473684211,5,0.263157895,0.210526316,0.157894737,0.052631579,0.842105263,9.000000009,9.000000009,4.000000004,3.000000003,1.000000001,16
120.7411,31.31054,东湖林语小区西门,1,18,0.555555556,6,0.333333333,0.444444444,0.5,0.388888889,0.388888889,10.00000001,10.00000001,7.999999992,9,7.000000002,7.000000002
120.7591,31.33735,亿城新天地南门,1,40,0.5,5,0.125,0.125,0.1,0.025,0.1,20,20,5,4,1,4
120.7247,31.28315,荣域小区东门,1,18,0.277777778,3,0.111111111,0.111111111,0.055555556,0.5,0.444444444,5.000000004,5.000000004,1.999999998,1.000000008,9,7.999999992
120.741,31.30539,朗诗国际小区西门,1,29,0.793103448,8,0.517241379,0.482758621,0.206896552,0.310344828,0.413793103,22.99999999,22.99999999,14.00000001,6.000000008,9.000000012,11.99999999
120.7668,31.30742,凤凰城小区西门,1,45,0.866666667,9,0.266666667,0.288888889,0.2,0.177777778,0.133333333,39.00000002,39.00000002,13.00000001,9,8.00000001,5.999999985
120.7041,31.32298,文化艺术中心北,1,30,0.1,1,0.333333333,0.5,0.433333333,0.4,0.466666667,3,3,15,12.99999999,12,14.00000001
120.7129,31.32304,时代广场站4号出口,1,40,0.05,1,0.15,0.65,0.425,0.475,0.8,2,2,26,17,19,32
120.7129,31.32218,时代广场站1号出口,1,20,0,1,0.4,1,0.45,0.45,0.45,0,0,20,9,9,9
120.7211,31.32248,星湖街站2号出口,1,30,0.1,1,0.733333333,0.366666667,0.166666667,0.066666667,0.1,3,3,11.00000001,5.00000001,2.00000001,3
120.733,31.32499,南施街站3号出口,1,40,0.025,1,0.825,0.675,0.7,0.75,0.775,1,1,27,28,30,31
120.7331,31.32366,南施街站1号出口,1,40,0.05,1,0.175,0.275,0.5,0.525,0.55,2,2,11,20,21,22
120.7439,31.32642,星塘街站1c号出口,1,20,0.1,1,1.45,1.35,1.5,1.55,1.55,2,2,27,30,31,31
120.7456,31.32557,星塘街站3号出口,1,40,0.1,1,0.7,0.2,0.325,0.575,0.6,4,4,8,13,23,24
120.7563,31.3269,钟南街站3号出口,1,20,0.25,3,1.1,1.25,1.35,1.35,1.4,5,5,25,27,27,28
120.7558,31.32605,钟南街站1号出口,1,40,0.125,2,0.8,0.825,0.625,0.725,0.675,5,5,33,25,29,27
120.721,31.3236,星湖街站3号出口,1,20,0.2,2,0.05,0.25,0.1,0.05,0.1,4,4,5,2,1,2
120.6961,31.32994,玲珑湾北门,1,32,0.3125,4,0.1875,0.0625,0,0,0,10,10,2,0,0,0
120.7225,31.32843,中央景城南门,1,20,1.15,10,0.3,0.25,0.1,0.05,0.05,23,23,5,2,1,1
120.7286,31.31926,圆融大厦邮政局,1,30,0.033333333,1,0.733333333,0.966666667,0.8,0.733333333,0.766666667,0.99999999,0.99999999,29.00000001,24,21.99999999,23.00000001
120.7285,31.31546,东湖大郡三期,1,20,0.4,4,0.1,0.1,0,0.05,0.5,8,8,2,0,1,10
120.7551,31.32111,水墨三十度,1,29,1.172413793,10,0.344827586,0.103448276,0.448275862,0.275862069,0.137931034,34,34,3.000000004,13,8.000000001,3.999999986
120.7756,31.30734,产业园,1,39,0.128205128,2,0.41025641,0.641025641,0.769230769,0.846153846,0.846153846,4.999999992,4.999999992,25,29.99999999,32.99999999,32.99999999
120.73093,31.301743,名湖家园,1,30,0.4,4,0.766666667,0.7,0.666666667,0.6,0.566666667,12,12,21,20.00000001,18,17.00000001
120.7643,31.33083,太阳城,1,31,0.258064516,3,0.096774194,0.290322581,0.096774194,0.225806452,0.129032258,7.999999996,7.999999996,9.000000011,3.000000014,7.000000012,3.999999998
120.725,31.28551,星湖名轩,1,30,0.1,1,0.533333333,0.4,0.133333333,0.1,0.466666667,3,3,12,3.99999999,3,14.00000001
120.744646,31.275451,苏大二期东,1,30,0.2,2,0.333333333,0.2,0.066666667,0.066666667,0.033333333,6,6,6,2.00000001,2.00000001,0.99999999
120.7383,31.26928,苏大一期东,1,30,0.166666667,2,0.966666667,0.5,0.433333333,0.266666667,0.166666667,5.00000001,5.00000001,15,12.99999999,8.00000001,5.00000001
120.739,31.2753,西交利物浦,1,30,0.1,1,0.4,0.466666667,0.866666667,0.5,0.533333333,3,3,14.00000001,26.00000001,15,15.99999999
120.7326,31.26539,创意产业园北,1,30,0,1,0.466666667,0.766666667,1.2,0.966666667,0.966666667,0,0,23.00000001,36,29.00000001,29.00000001
120.731,31.2627,创意产业园西,1,40,0,1,0.15,0.5,0.675,0.075,0.55,0,0,20,27,3,22
120.7309,31.25876,生物纳米园,1,40,0.025,1,0.125,0.75,0.525,0.575,0.525,1,1,30,21,23,21
120.7353,31.25612,中科纳米所,1,30,0.466666667,5,0.466666667,0.466666667,0.466666667,0.466666667,0.466666667,14.00000001,14.00000001,14.00000001,14.00000001,14.00000001,14.00000001
120.7379,31.26553,创意产业园东,1,30,0,1,0.366666667,1.166666667,1,0.6,0.733333333,0,0,35.00000001,30,18,21.99999999
120.7357,31.25256,腾飞创新园,1,28,0.035714286,1,0.107142857,0.464285714,0.107142857,0,0.071428571,1.000000008,1.000000008,12.99999999,2.999999996,0,1.999999988
120.728,31.24961,菁英公寓北,1,38,0.5,5,0.763157895,0.052631579,0,0.026315789,0.078947368,19,19,2.000000002,0,0.999999982,2.999999984
120.745,31.27613,翰林邻里中心,1,40,0.1,1,0.875,0.075,0,0.05,0,4,4,3,0,2,0
120.7425,31.27572,文星广场,1,36,0.138888889,2,0.138888889,0.166666667,0,0,0.055555556,5.000000004,5.000000004,6.000000012,0,0,2.000000016
120.7426,31.2755,港大思培学院,1,30,0.033333333,1,0.133333333,0.233333333,0,0.033333333,0.066666667,0.99999999,0.99999999,6.99999999,0,0.99999999,2.00000001
120.7309,31.27532,苏州大学北,1,30,0.033333333,1,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.99999999,0.99999999,9,18,18,18
120.7272,31.27527,综合楼,1,30,0.266666667,3,0.5,0.7,0.9,0.866666667,0.533333333,8.00000001,8.00000001,21,27,26.00000001,15.99999999
120.7223,31.27533,独墅湖图书馆,1,40,0.25,3,0.4,0.45,0.425,0.425,0.425,10,10,18,17,17,17
120.7227,31.26961,白鹭园,1,30,0.5,5,0.533333333,0.233333333,0.1,0.066666667,0.1,15,15,6.99999999,3,2.00000001,3
120.7248,31.26273,教育发展大厦,1,30,0.366666667,4,0.066666667,0.333333333,0.5,0.6,0.6,11.00000001,11.00000001,9.99999999,15,18,18
120.7235,31.26027,星月坊商业街,1,30,0.633333333,7,0.466666667,0.4,0.333333333,0.233333333,0.133333333,18.99999999,18.99999999,12,9.99999999,6.99999999,3.99999999
120.7277,31.26291,星湖街月亮湾,1,30,0.1,1,0.033333333,0.066666667,0.033333333,0.033333333,0.033333333,3,3,2.00000001,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999
120.7434,31.27071,体育公园东,1,30,0,1,0,0.333333333,0.733333333,0.833333333,0.833333333,0,0,9.99999999,21.99999999,24.99999999,24.99999999
120.7474,31.27744,翰林缘,1,40,0.6,6,0.1,0,0,0,0,24,24,0,0,0,0
120.7483,31.2697,文汇广场,1,40,0.55,6,0.1,0.375,0.025,0.275,0.375,22,22,15,1,11,15
120.7494,31.26765,公交首末站,1,40,0.475,5,0.425,0.15,0.025,0.05,0.45,19,19,6,1,2,18
120.7422,31.26143,工业技术学校,1,30,0.1,1,0.566666667,0.6,0.833333333,0.866666667,0.866666667,3,3,18,24.99999999,26.00000001,26.00000001
120.7469,31.26229,评弹学校,1,28,0.785714286,8,0.964285714,0.107142857,0.142857143,0.071428571,0.107142857,22.00000001,22.00000001,2.999999996,4.000000004,1.999999988,2.999999996
120.7494,31.25789,服务外包学院,1,28,0,1,0.25,0.607142857,0.464285714,0.5,0.5,0,0,17,12.99999999,14,14
120.7534,31.25906,职业技术学院,1,30,0.766666667,8,0.8,1,0.666666667,0.466666667,0.5,23.00000001,23.00000001,30,20.00000001,14.00000001,15
120.7265,31.26683,独墅湖影剧院,1,40,0.15,2,0.475,0.55,0.35,0.25,0.175,6,6,22,14,10,7
120.7231,31.26697,月亮湾国际中心,1,30,0.033333333,1,0.466666667,0.733333333,0.633333333,0.633333333,0.633333333,0.99999999,0.99999999,21.99999999,18.99999999,18.99999999,18.99999999
120.7291,31.26946,苏大文景路,1,30,0.233333333,3,0.033333333,0.8,0.466666667,0.5,0.5,6.99999999,6.99999999,24,14.00000001,15,15
120.7201,31.31773,建屋国际酒店东门,1,16,0.5625,6,0.5,0.75,0.3125,0.3125,0.375,9,9,12,5,5,6
120.7311,31.29746,荷韵新村东区西门,1,46,0.543478261,6,0.326086957,0.043478261,0.02173913,0,0,25.00000001,25.00000001,2.000000006,0.99999998,0,0
120.7418,31.29948,莲香北区南门,1,32,0.125,2,0.0625,0.03125,0.0625,0.53125,0.46875,4,4,1,2,17,15
120.7376,31.29842,斜塘医院,1,26,0.153846154,2,0.423076923,0.230769231,0.269230769,0.346153846,0.423076923,4.000000004,4.000000004,6.000000006,6.999999994,8.999999996,11
120.7336,31.29539,荷花公园,1,42,0.047619048,1,0.047619048,0.119047619,0.30952381,0.285714286,0.261904762,2.000000016,2.000000016,4.999999998,13.00000002,12.00000001,11
120.7431,31.29161,斜塘农贸市场,1,46,0.5,5,0.347826087,0.304347826,0.152173913,0.065217391,0.02173913,23,23,14,6.999999998,2.999999986,0.99999998
120.7404,31.29613,莲香三区南,1,36,0.027777778,1,0.083333333,0.416666667,0.361111111,0.416666667,0.388888889,1.000000008,1.000000008,15.00000001,13,15.00000001,14
120.7293,31.29526,荷韵农贸市场,1,26,0.807692308,9,0.961538462,0.038461538,0.423076923,0.615384615,0.346153846,21.00000001,21.00000001,0.999999988,11,15.99999999,8.999999996
120.7283,31.29441,绿洲别墅,1,30,0.1,1,0.533333333,0.566666667,0.5,0.433333333,0.533333333,3,3,17.00000001,15,12.99999999,15.99999999
120.7283,31.2863,顺达商业广场南,1,40,0.475,5,0.225,0.15,0.15,0.225,0.3,19,19,6,6,9,12
120.7294,31.28737,顺达商业广场东,1,36,0.694444444,7,0.222222222,0.277777778,0.305555556,0.555555556,0.583333333,24.99999998,24.99999998,10.00000001,11.00000002,20.00000002,20.99999999
120.7317,31.28628,莲花六区南门,1,34,0.882352941,9,0.264705882,0.411764706,0.117647059,0.058823529,0.029411765,29.99999999,29.99999999,14,4.000000006,1.999999986,1.00000001
120.7351,31.28633,莲花四区南门,1,34,0.411764706,5,0,0,0.676470588,0.705882353,0.647058824,14,14,0,22.99999999,24,22.00000002
120.7442,31.28629,莲花二区南门,1,34,0.5,5,0.029411765,0.029411765,0,0.264705882,0.264705882,17,17,1.00000001,0,8.999999988,8.999999988
120.7445,31.28592,莲花一区北门,1,32,0.28125,3,0.40625,0.09375,0.3125,0.3125,0.34375,9,9,3,10,10,11
120.7381,31.28411,莲花农贸市场,1,28,0.821428571,9,0.75,0.357142857,0.071428571,0,0.571428571,22.99999999,22.99999999,9.999999996,1.999999988,0,15.99999999
120.7311,31.28599,莲花五区北门,1,34,0.970588235,,0.588235294,0.205882353,0.058823529,0.029411765,0.058823529,32.99999999,32.99999999,7.000000002,1.999999986,1.00000001,1.999999986
120.7387,31.28705,莲花商业街,1,30,0.3,3,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.4,0.3,9,9,12,15,12,9
120.7293,31.29897,荷韵新村北门,1,40,0.875,9,0.05,0.225,0.175,0.225,0.175,35,35,9,7,9,7
120.731,31.30033,金色尚城,1,28,0.571428571,6,0.892857143,0.642857143,0.107142857,0.035714286,0.285714286,15.99999999,15.99999999,18,2.999999996,1.000000008,8.000000008
120.7364,31.2958,联丰广场南,1,36,0.194444444,2,0.416666667,0.5,0.527777778,0.305555556,0.527777778,6.999999984,6.999999984,18,19.00000001,11.00000002,19.00000001
120.7429,31.29595,敦煌一区北门,1,28,0.25,3,0,0.5,0.5,0.357142857,0.25,7,7,14,14,9.999999996,7
120.7381,31.29372,敦煌三区北门,1,26,0.538461538,6,0.384615385,0.076923077,0.153846154,0.153846154,0.153846154,13.99999999,13.99999999,2.000000002,4.000000004,4.000000004,4.000000004
120.7294,31.29025,莲花八区东门,1,28,0.892857143,9,0.107142857,0,0,0.642857143,0.607142857,25,25,0,0,18,17
120.7461,31.29899,斜塘欧尚超市,1,40,0.1,1,0.525,0.275,0.55,0.925,0.425,4,4,11,22,37,17
120.7338,31.28916,莲花六区东门,1,28,0.535714286,6,0.071428571,0.107142857,0.107142857,0.642857143,0.642857143,15.00000001,15.00000001,2.999999996,2.999999996,18,18
120.734,31.28268,莲花五区东门,1,28,0.857142857,9,0,0.107142857,0,0,0,24,24,2.999999996,0,0,0
120.7384,31.28889,莲花四区东门,1,34,0.852941176,9,0.029411765,0.352941176,0.176470588,0.058823529,0.147058824,28.99999998,28.99999998,11.99999998,5.999999992,1.999999986,5.000000016
120.7299,31.29194,娄葑高新公司,1,26,0.692307692,7,0.653846154,0.538461538,0.461538462,0.423076923,0.423076923,17.99999999,17.99999999,13.99999999,12.00000001,11,11
120.7346,31.28576,莲花三区北门,1,36,0.555555556,6,0,0.361111111,0.222222222,0.277777778,0.194444444,20.00000002,20.00000002,13,7.999999992,10.00000001,6.999999984
120.7471,31.2486,星坊便利中心,1,44,0.613636364,7,0.5,0.454545455,0.318181818,0.340909091,0.25,27.00000002,27.00000002,20.00000002,13.99999999,15,11
120.7446,31.24332,淞泽家园一区,1,34,0.058823529,1,0.529411765,0,0.294117647,0,0.029411765,1.999999986,1.999999986,0,9.999999998,0,1.00000001
120.7391,31.24726,淞泽家园四区,1,30,0.1,1,0.233333333,0.1,0.033333333,0.333333333,0.366666667,3,3,3,0.99999999,9.99999999,11.00000001
120.7437,31.24263,淞泽家园九区,1,28,0.892857143,9,0.392857143,0.571428571,0,0.107142857,0.107142857,25,25,15.99999999,0,2.999999996,2.999999996
120.7374,31.24522,车坊农贸市场北,1,28,0.928571429,10,1.035714286,0.357142857,0.321428571,0.142857143,0.178571429,26.00000001,26.00000001,9.999999996,8.999999988,4.000000004,5.000000012
120.7354,31.2443,星湖财富广场,1,34,0.411764706,5,0.705882353,0.294117647,0.117647059,0.147058824,0.147058824,14,14,9.999999998,4.000000006,5.000000016,5.000000016
120.7319,31.24297,淞泽家园八区,1,38,0.421052632,5,0.315789474,0,0,0.5,0.473684211,16.00000002,16.00000002,0,0,19,18.00000002
120.7294,31.24174,淞泽家园七区,1,28,0.035714286,1,0.035714286,0,0.071428571,0.5,0.464285714,1.000000008,1.000000008,0,1.999999988,14,12.99999999
120.7343,31.24061,江滨公园,1,34,0.705882353,8,0.441176471,0.323529412,0.294117647,0.294117647,0.264705882,24,24,11.00000001,9.999999998,9.999999998,8.999999988
120.742,31.24965,淞泽家园二区,1,24,1.208333333,10,0.666666667,0.041666667,0,0.541666667,0.583333333,28.99999999,28.99999999,1.000000008,0,13.00000001,13.99999999
120.7372,31.24758,淞泽家园六区,1,30,0.633333333,7,0.233333333,0,0,0,0.066666667,18.99999999,18.99999999,0,0,0,2.00000001
120.752,31.24938,普惠路永庆路,1,34,0.323529412,4,0.470588235,0.470588235,0.441176471,0.441176471,0.411764706,11.00000001,11.00000001,15.99999999,15.00000001,15.00000001,14
120.7561,31.25085,南澳花园,1,22,0.272727273,3,0.454545455,0.454545455,0.636363636,0.590909091,0.545454545,6.000000006,6.000000006,10.00000001,13.99999999,13,11.99999999
120.7435,31.33423,白塘景苑东门,1,40,0.375,4,0.55,0.6,0.575,0.45,0.4,15,15,24,23,18,16
120.7181,31.29509,金鸡湖邻里中心,1,40,0.05,1,0.25,0.225,0.275,0.4,0.525,2,2,9,11,16,21
120.7564,31.33397,东沙湖邻里中心,1,40,0.1,1,0.375,0.375,0.55,0.575,0.5,4,4,15,22,23,20
120.7286,31.31829,苏州银行,1,44,0.022727273,1,0.25,0.681818182,1,0.772727273,0.818181818,1.000000012,1.000000012,30.00000001,44,34.00000001,35.99999999
```

Comment: We cannot see your plot, as your example is not reproducible (we don't have access to `b` and `bike` dataset). Please insert a link in your question.

Comment: I have upload the full code and the data, thanks for notice.